# Brackets Colors Typescript vim-polyglot

Tags: typescript, vim

everyone

Someone can help me in this bug with vim-polyglot, i have an installation of vim-polyglot and vim-styled-components to syntax in the editor, but i see a bug in the color of brackets tags.

This is the way like see it in typescript:

[image: This is the way like see it in typescript]

If you can see, in the style part of view the pair brackets colors is different that's create a lot of confusion in a large code.

And this is the way like see it in javascript:

[image: And this is the way like see it in javascript]

How can i modify the colors of typescript in vim-polyglot?

Comment: How about opening an issue in the plugin's issue tracker?